# RegEx matching String not matching patterns and not blank

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx that matches when the string is not 1234, not 6789, and not blank.

- 1234 -> not a match
- 6789 -> not a match
- [blank] -> not a match
- abc -> match
- 5431 -> match

The RegEx engine is the one bundled in the JDK 6, if that matters.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself? SO is not 'gimme an answer and I'm gonna do nothing' site

Comment: Please post what you've tried. It'll help us guide you in the right direction, and you'll get much more out of it than someone posting a solution for you.

Comment: Are blanks allowed with text eg "ab cd"

Comment: I tried a bunch of stuff with Negative Lookaheads and Negative Lookarounds. Looks like @Bohemian was able to answer correctly, as my tests are now passing.

Comment: Should `012345` match or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using negative look aheads:

```
^(?!.*1234.*$)(?!.*5677.*$)(?!=\s*$).+
```

Comment: Thank you. I see my problem was trying to lump 1234 and 5678 in the same pattern like this: (1234|5678).

Comment: Yeah I initially went to code an OR, but it doesn't work because one is not the other so they are both allowed. Separate assertions are AND logic

Answer (score 0):

This negative lookahead should work:

```
^(?!.*?\b(1234|5677)\b).+$
```

- Word boundaries `\b` is to make sure that you don't disallow `11234` and `56777` etc.
- `.+` will make sure to not to match blank input.